# Android calendar set today's date and stop user from selecting a date in the past

Tags: android, date, datetime, calendar, integer

Hello I'm trying to set the date of my date picker when its clicked currently when the user clicks my txtdate it will present the date 15/05/2016 which is located at the bottom of my code. But I want the date to automatically update to be the current days date but I'm not sure how to add this to my code. I'm also trying to restrict the user from being able to select dates in the past. Any input would be most beneficial.

```
    txtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    int month=monthOfYear+1;
                    String date= dayOfMonth+"";



                    int time = year + monthOfYear + dayOfMonth;

                    if(date.length()==1)
                        date="0"+date;
                    date=month+date;
                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                    int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(date);
                    if(dateInt<=630 && dateInt>=605)
                        txtStatus.setText("Closed");
                    else
                        txtStatus.setText("Open");

                }

            },2016,05, 15);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Clearer example

Answer (score 0):

Global Variable

```
int year_x, month_x, day_x;
```

OnCreate

```
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    year_x = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

OnDataSet

```
 @Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

year_x = year;
month_x = monthOfYear;
day_x = dayOfMonth;
```

Change bottom line static date

from

```
},2016,05, 15);
```

to

```
}, year_x,month_x,day_x);
```